# Calculating employee's salary using class and object

Tags: java

I have to write a program to calculate the employees' salary using getter and setter. I have a problem regarding how to display the calculated salary of the employees. It doesn't show the salary.

Here is what I've done so far:

employee.java

```java
public class employee {

    private String firstName,lastName;
    private int hours;
    private double wage,salary;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(int hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public double getWage() {
        return wage;
    }

    public void setWage(double wage) {
        this.wage = wage;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        salary = getWage()* getHours();
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {

        this.salary = salary;
    }}
```

main.java

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of employees : ");
        int n = input.nextInt();

        employee[] emp = new employee[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < emp.length; i++) {
            emp[i] = new employee();

            System.out.println("enter employee" + (i + 1) + " first name : ");
            emp[i].setFirstName(input.next());

            System.out.println("enter employee" + (i + 1) + " last name : ");
            emp[i].setLastName(input.next());

            System.out.println("enter employee" + (i + 1) + " wage : ");
            emp[i].setWage(input.nextInt());

            System.out.println("enter employee" + (i + 1) + " number of working hours : ");
            emp[i].setHours(input.nextInt());

            System.out.println("salary of employee" + (i + 1) + " is : ");
            emp[i].getSalary();

        }
        int index = 0;
        for (employee temp :
                emp) {
            System.out.println("employee" + (++index) + "first name" + temp.getFirstName());
            System.out.println("employee" + (++index) + "last name" + temp.getLastName());
            System.out.println("employee" + (++index) + "wage" + temp.getWage());
            System.out.println("employee" + (++index) + "num of working hours" + temp.getHours());
            System.out.println("employee" + (++index) + "salary" + temp.getSalary());

        }
    }
```

Comment: You never set the salary, in the first loop you have `emp[i].getSalary();` but it should be `setSalary` like you set all the other fields.

Comment: Please learn and follow the Java coding standards.  Should be Employee - class names are capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

First, your `getSalary()` method probably should not **calculate** (and **set**) the salary field as a side-effect; currently `setSalary(double)` is misleading (and whatever would be set would be ignored). It isn't clear why you even have a `salary` field. Perhaps you should eliminate it (and the setter) then it would be clearer. As for your actual question,

```
System.out.println("salary of employee" + (i + 1) + " is : ");
emp[i].getSalary();
```

Gets a value, but you don't actually attempt to display it. You need a `print`. Like,

```
System.out.printf("salary of employee%d is %.2f%n",
        i, emp[i].getSalary());
```

Comment: @MaartenBodewes You think `getSalary()` ***should*** have the side-effect of setting `salary`? Eliminating the field entirely would make more sense to me.

Comment: Maybe the `getSalary()` method is supposed to calculate and return the salary, and there shouldn't be a `salary` field. The question does not have clear requirements.

Comment: @khelwood Now that sounds more reasonable.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, for instance. What you should not do is store hours and wage *and* salary if they are linked.

Comment: The answer still indicates that you should not calculate it. I'm pretty sure that part of the assignment is to calculate the salary from hours and wage.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Good point. It wasn't the calculate I really objected to. It was the setting of a field as a side-effect of a get.

Comment: Now that **is** bad :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the `employee` class is to store information about an employee. However, in pure object oriented programming, you'd also have *active methods* that perform actions on instances of this `employee` class. Now in the domain of employment, you may want to calculate the salary from the hours and wages. One way to do that is to have an hours and wage field and then calculate the salary from it. However, that precludes the use of a "setter" that sets the salary.

Instead, you'd calculate the salary from the hours and wages when requested, e.g. using a method called `calculateSalary()`. That method should **not** set a field, it should simply perform the calculation on the `hours` and `wage` fields (using *local* variables in the scope of the method where required). **If** you do set such a field then you can have a class that has an *inconsistent state*, i.e. the wage and hours may differ from the salary stored. This is something that you should always try and prevent; always try and store the *minimum amount of information / state* and keep it consistent.

```
public double calculateSalary() {
    return wage * hours;
}
```

Notes:

- "hours worked" is generally not thought of as a *property* of an employee as it is too dynamic for that; for this *model* in the assignment it is probably OK though. For *more complex models* you could e.g. have a `SalaryCalculator` class that takes an employee (and / or wage) and the number of hours worked.
- Internal methods have access to the fields directly. It is bad practice to directly call other public methods (which may be overridden by other classes) instead of using the fields directly. In other words, don't call `getWage()` or `getHours()` from within `calculateSalary()`.
- `employee` is a class / type, which in Java (and most other languages) starts off with a capital letter, i.e. `Employee`.

Comment: I could go into builders, immutable objects, factory methods etc. but I guess this is enough for one question :)

Answer (score -1):

The alternative method you can do is make a constructor in employee.java like this:

```
public employee(String firstName,String lastName,int hours,double wage, 
double salary){
this.firstName=firstName;
this.lastName=lastName;
this.hours=hours
this.wage=wage;
this.salary=salary;
}
```

Now in the main.java file you can set the details like this:
Employee employee = new Employee(firstName,lastName,hours,wage,salary);

Now you can use the get function to get the values.